# how to sum just 1 previous value in a list

Tags: python, sum

I have a list and want to sum the value of index(-1) with current value index for the whole list

```
list = [-2, -2, -1, 1, -1, 1, 3, 5, 6, -2, -1, 0, -2, -1, -2, 2]
```

Expected output:

```
new_list =[-2,-4,-3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 8, 11, 4, -3, -1, -2, -3, -3, 0]
```

```
new_list[0] = 0+ list[0]  = 0+ (-2) = -2
new_list[1] = list[0] + list[1] = (-2) + (-2) = -4
new_list[2] = list[1] + list[2] = (-2)+ (-1) = -3
new_list[3] = list[2] + list[3] = (-1)+ (1) = 0

Basically new_list[index] = list[index -1] + list[index]
```

Comment: your input and expected output don't seem to match what you're describing

Comment: `list(map(sum, zip(l,l[1:])))`

Comment: `new_list = [list[x] + list[x-1] if x != 0 else list[x] for x in range(len(list))]` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
list1 = [-2, -2, -1, 1, -1, 1, 3, 5, 6, -2, -1, 0, -2, -1, -2, 2]
new_list=[list1[0]]
for i in range(len(list1)-1):
    value=list1[i]+list1[i+1]
    new_list.append(value)


print(new_list)
Output:[-2,-4,-3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 8, 11, 4, -3, -1, -2, -3, -3, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> list = [-2, -2, -1, 1, -1, 1, 3, 5, 6, -2, -1, 0, -2, -1, -2, 2]
>>> list_length = len(list)
>>> result_list = [list[0]]
>>> for i in range(list_length):
...     if not (i+1) == list_length:
...             result_list.append(list[i] + list[i+1])
...
>>> result_list
[2, -4, -3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 8, 11, 4, -3, -1, -2, -3, -3, 0]
```

The above is the solution of your quest.

Comment: Seems to me that this doesn't match the requested output

Comment: Actually, he is making a mistake by including the first value of the array. Because there is no such a sum to get that number. On the other hand, just initializing the empty array with the first element of the list is the simplest solution. There is no need of mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate on the list and add the numbers like so:

```py
list = [-2, -2, -1, 1, -1, 1, 3, 5, 6, -2, -1, 0, -2, -1, -2, 2]

new_list = list[0] # We just take the first element of the list, because we don't add anything

for number, element in enumerate(list[1:]):
    new_list.append(element + list[number - 1])
```

Or a more pythonic way:

```py
new_list = [list[0]].extend([element + list[number - 1] for number, element in enumerate (list[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you can do this quite easily with `pandas`.  For example:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a pandas Series of values
s = pd.Series([-2, -2, -1, 1, -1, 1, 3, 5, 6, -2, -1, 0, -2, -1, -2, 2])
# Add the current value in the series to the 'shifted' (previous) value.
output = s.add(s.shift(1), fill_value=0).tolist()
# Display the output.
print(output)
```

Output:

```
[-2.0, -4.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 8.0, 11.0, 4.0, -3.0, -1.0, -2.0, -3.0, -3.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: Seems to me that this doesn't match the requested output